# Kubuntu 13.10 changing x mode after login

Tags: nvidia, xorg, kubuntu, resolution

I have a QNIX 2710 monitor which reports bad EDID. Using the nouveau module the screen works fine @ 2560x1440 however the performance isn't ideal so I wish to use the nvidia binary.

I have installed the binary fine, used nvidia-xconfig to generate an xorg.conf and then hand edited that conf to suit the monitor.

I can get to the graphical login greeter in Kubuntu 13.10 while using the nvidia binary, which to me says it is working. However, when I log in KDE brings up its usual little window in the middle showing the login progress. When the second icon starts to appear the screen blanks and then goes in to a test pattern. This is how the screen behaves when the incorrect resolution is set- it has no scaler.

So I can only conclude that the mode is changing post login. Some digging found nvidia-auto-detect going for 800x600, which will never work.

I have crafted an xorg.conf which should work with the monitor. I have set it to ignore EDID :

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 304.88  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06)  Wed Mar 27 15:32:58 PDT 2013

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       88.8
    VertRefresh     59.5
    Modeline "2560x1440"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
    DisplaySize 597 336
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    Modes "2560x1440"
    Option "UseEDID" "False"
       Option "UseEDIDDPI" "False"
    Option "UseEDIDFreqs" "False"
    Option "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "True"

### Metamode for single QX2710 (2560x1440)
#   Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: 2560x1440 +0 +0"     
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

In closing, my question is, how / why does the mode change post login? Are there additional xorg.conf's or some such somewhere that apply after login?

Thanks in advance.

-LC

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to fix this in an elegant way but I was able to plug in a monitor that supported 800x600, then changed the resolution to 2560x1440, which was the only other available resolution. Once doing that it has been fine through reboots etc.